# Filtering SQL rows using column data

Tags: sql, filter, rows

I am trying to filter rows in a single table. My goal is to return all license plates that have "entered" a building but have not "exited" the building prior to 11am on July 28, 2021.

Here is the code I have written which of course returns all rows for that day.

```
SELECT *
FROM bakery_security_logs
WHERE day = '28' and
      month = '7' and
      year = '2021' and
      hour < '11'
ORDER BY month, day, year;
```

Here is what this code returns:
[image]

Comment: If you Order By license_plate, then year, month, day, hour, Id then you should have yourself a sequence of entrance exit pairs of which the LAST one is what you want if it is of type 'entrance'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution 1 - Group and compare how many times entered or exited.

You can group by license_plate first, count how many times the vehicle has entered and exited the building. If the building has entered and exited before 11AM, `entranceCount` and `exitCount` should be the same.

However, if the vehicle entered on 27 Nov, and left on 28 Nov, this may not work.

```
SELECT license_plate
FROM (
  SELECT
    license_plate,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN activity = 'entrance' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS entranceCount,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN activity = 'exit' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS exitCount
  FROM bakery_security_logs
  WHERE day = '28' and
        month = '7' and
        year = '2021' and
        hour < '11'
  GROUP BY license_plate
)
WHERE entranceCount > exitCount
-- WHERE entranceCount != exitCount
   -- if exitCount > entranceCount, may need to be alerted too
```

---

### Solution 2 - Get the latest record and check activity

Get the latest record of each `license_plate`. If `activity = 'entrance'`, the vehicle is still in the building by 11 AM.

This is more efficient but the syntax may be different, depending on which SQL server you are using.

---

### Additional suggestion

Use `DATETIME` to record a datetime, it will be helpful for filtering and sorting the data.

Answer (score 0):

I like this (MySQL) "one-liner":

```
SELECT 
        license_plate, 
        max(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(year, '-',  LPAD(month, 2, '0'), '-',  LPAD(day, 2, '0'), ' ', LPAD(hour, 2, '0'), ':', LPAD(minute, 2, '0')), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'))    date_time,
        max(activity) activity
    FROM bakery_security_logs
    WHERE day = '28' and
        month = '7' and
        year = '2021' and
        hour < '11'
    GROUP BY license_plate
    HAVING activity = 'entrance'
    ORDER BY date_time;
```